# Migration to/from not found while creating migration script with ASP.NET Core tools

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use the command `dotnet ef migrations script` in order to create an SQL script for between the last applied migration and the last not applied migration. Applied migration is one for which is called `dotnet ef database update`

I try to execute the following commands and none of them works:

```
dotnet ef  --startup-project ../DbMigrations/ migrations script from LastAppliedMigration to LastNotAppliedMigration -o temp.sql --context MyProject.DbModel.MusicDbContext

dotnet ef  --startup-project ../DbMigrations/ migrations script from LastAppliedMigration -o temp.sql --context MyProject.DbModel.MusicDbContext
```

I get the following error: **System.InvalidOperationException: The migration 'from' was not found.**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The migration 'from' was not found.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsAssemblyExtensions.GetMigrationId(IMigrationsAssembly assembly, String nameOrId)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateScript(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.ScriptMigration(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsScriptCommand.Execute(CommonOptions commonOptions, String from, String to, String output, Boolean idempotent, String context, String environment)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsScriptCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

For migration names I tried both versions with the prefix timestamp and without:

1. 20160920085915_LastAppliedMigration
2. LastAppliedMigration

Do I use this command `dotnet ef migrations script` correctly?

**Edit 1**

I did a simple example to demonstrate the issue which I have. The example can be downloaded from here [Download example](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkypHMylcA0XiYt-5xaPY7dJaMMkPQ)

What I did:

1. Created a default web application project
2. `dotnet ef migrations add Initial`
3. `dotnet ef migrations script -o initial.sql` -- the initial.sql file was created
4. `dotnet ef database update`
5. Added `Student` class in `Data`
6. Added ``DbSet`in`ApplicationDbContext```
7. `dotnet ef migrations add Student`
8. `dotnet ef migrations script from 20160924174811_Initial -o student.sql`

Here I get the following error -- The migration 'from' was not found.

```
Project WebApplication3 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.              
System.InvalidOperationException: The migration 'from' was not found.                                          
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsAssemblyExtensions.GetMigrationId(IMigrationsAssembly assembly, String nameOrId)                                                                                     
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateScript(String fromMigration, String to Migration, Boolean idempotent)                                                                                 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.ScriptMigration(String fromMigration, String to Migration, Boolean idempotent, String contextType)                                                             
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsScriptCommand.Execute(CommonOptions commonOptions, String from, String to, String output, Boolean idempotent, String context, String environment)                     
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsScriptCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()   
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)                      
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)                                      
The migration 'from' was not found.
```

When I do `dotnet ef migrations list` I get the following result:

```
Project WebApplication3 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
20160924174811_Initial
20160924175511_Student
```

The version of the CLI tools is

```
dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-003131
```

Comment: The second version should work. What version of the CLI tools are you using?

Comment: Mike Mike, I have added Edit 1 with a demo application demonstrating my issue. I am trying to make ```dotnet ef migrations script from 20160924174811_Initial -o student.sql``` and it does not work with the error: The migration 'from' was not found. You can download the attached project and have a look. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out.

`from` is not an option name and on its place should come directly the migration name.

Working command examples below:

`dotnet ef migrations script Initial -o student.sql`

or also is valid

`dotnet ef migrations script 20160924174811_Initial -o student2.sql`